# What if I run "docker compose up -d" multiple times?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

we have a shell script that runs `docker compose -f abc.yml up -d`. It works fine.

However, sometimes, we have to re-run the script for some reason. This would also re-run `docker compose -f abc up -d`.

I wonder if the re-run could cause issues to the docker compose containers? Would docker remove existing containers and start new ones? Influence volumes? Influence data?

I also wonder if there is a good method to detect if a specific docker compose is already launched before?

---

Though I can manually run the command multiple times, but I want theoretical confirmation from the community.

Comment: Just try running it a couple times but without the script. If the yaml file hasn't changed, nothing will happen. You'll see that it checks the containers and exits if there's nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @anemyte, I tried to manually re-run `docker compose -f abc.yml up -d` multiple times, and found Docker is smart enough to not recreating existing containers. See output below.

```
ubuntu@ip-127.0.0.1:~$ docker compose -f abc.yml up -d                                                                                                                           [33/2451]
[+] Running 5/5
 ✔ Container dependency_services-zipkin-1     Started                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.9s
 ✔ Container dependency_services-redis-1      Started                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1.0s
 ✔ Container dependency_services-grpcbin-1    Started                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1.0s
 ✔ Container dependency_services-cassandra-1  Started                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.7s
 ✔ Container dependency_services-postgres-1   Started                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1.0s
ubuntu@ip-127.0.0.1:~$ docker compose -f abc.yml up -d
[+] Running 5/0
 ✔ Container dependency_services-cassandra-1  Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 ✔ Container dependency_services-redis-1      Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 ✔ Container dependency_services-grpcbin-1    Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 ✔ Container dependency_services-zipkin-1     Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 ✔ Container dependency_services-postgres-1   Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
ubuntu@ip-127.0.0.1:~$ docker compose -f abc.yml up -d
[+] Running 5/0
 ✔ Container dependency_services-redis-1      Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 ✔ Container dependency_services-grpcbin-1    Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 ✔ Container dependency_services-zipkin-1     Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 ✔ Container dependency_services-postgres-1   Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 ✔ Container dependency_services-cassandra-1  Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
ubuntu@ip-127.0.0.1:~$ docker compose -f abc.yml up -d
[+] Running 5/0
 ✔ Container dependency_services-zipkin-1     Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 ✔ Container dependency_services-redis-1      Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 ✔ Container dependency_services-postgres-1   Running
```